# когда вызываю метод объекта внутри другого метода из этого же объекта через this, выдает ошибку "no function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Вот мой код.
Что я хочу сделать?
Хочу внутри одного объекта использовать его методы.
Не получается. 
При вызове метода cancelAdd с использованием this, внутри метода start, node.js ругается, говорит, что метод cancelAdd - not function.
Помогите пожалуйста, мне не хватает знаний.

```
const config = require('../config/config');

const dictionaryOperations = (bot) =>{
    return {
        start: function (msg) {
            let chatId = msg.chat.id;
            let message = 'Welcome!\nThis bot can save words as dictionary';
            let options = {
              "reply_markup": {
                  "keyboard": [[config.replyKeyboard.addWordButton]],
                  "resize_keyboard": true,
              }
            };
            bot.sendMessage(chatId, message, options);
            this.cancelAdd(msg);
        },
        cancelAdd: function (msg) {
            console.log( `cancel action`);
            bot.send(msg.chat.id, 'Cancel action');
        },
    }

};

module.exports = dictionaryOperations;
```

А метод start я вызываю в файле app.js
Ниже код

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('./config/config');
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

require('./config/configDB');

const app = express();
const bot = new TelegramBot (config.TOKEN);
bot.setWebHook(config.URL);

const dictionary = require('./controllers/dictionaryControllers')(bot);

app.listen(3000);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.post('/', (request, response)=>{
    let req = request.body;
    response.send().status(200);
    bot.processUpdate(req);
});

const start = /\/start/;
bot.onText(start, dictionary.start);
```

Comment: покажи как ты это используешь. Предоставленный код вполне работает.

Comment: также, обрати внимание. что  `msg` вот тут `(msg) => { ` и тут `func1: function(msg) { ` и `func2: function(msg) {` - Это разные, ничем не связанные между собой переменные

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв.
Не совсем понял, Ваш ответ.
Почему же? msg - параметр везде одинаковый.
но вот через this.func2(msg) функция не вызывается ((( Говорит, что это не функция,

Comment: одинаковое название параметра, не означает одинаковые значения в момент выполнения.

Comment: _через this.func2(msg) функция не вызывается ((( Говорит, что это не функция_ - так покажи как именно ты используешь приведенный код.

Comment: как можешь заметить в [примере](http://jsfiddle.net/bLu05hya/) - твой код отрабатывает именно так как надо, без ошибок. Следовательно проблема заключается в том, как именно ты его вызываешь

Comment: Спасибо за Вашу активность.
Вот скриншот кода + консоль+ телеграм
http://prntscr.com/lh16tj
Вот непременно сам код => https://jsbin.com/yubezikija/edit?js,output

Comment: Добавь все необходимое непосредственно в вопрос, код как код, а не картинку.

Comment: под _как именно ты его вызываешь_ - имелось ввиду место где ты вызываешь метод `start` и как именно ты это делаешь

Comment: Кто и как вызывает метод `start`?

Comment: Понял) Дополнил описание.
Спасибо.

И прощу прощения, я новичок здесь